# How to get breadcrumbs to work for Salesforce Apex files in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, apex, breadcrumbs, outline, cls

In visual Studio Code, I can see that Breadcrumbs works for e.g. html files in my project, but not for Apex classes. I get Breadcrumbs for folder all the way to file, but not inside the cls file. I know this has worked before, so I'm wondering if someone can help me troubleshoot or direct me to the settings/updates I have to do.

The same goes for the file outline. It is empty for cls files but not for etc. html files.

I use a docker container and i have installed the Salesforce Extension pack and the Salesforce Extension pack (Expanded).

Comment: the language provider implements these parts, for HTML/JavaScript/... it is build in. If Apex is a different languageID ask the maintainers of that language extension

Comment: make sure these extensions run in the remote

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Needed to update the java version in the devcontainer.js

```
"settings": {
        "salesforcedx-vscode-apex.java.home": "/usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64"
      },
```